# Converting C# Encryption Algorithm to Ruby

Tags: c#, ruby, encryption, aes

Hi i have an encryption algorithm in c#, and i need to port it to ruby.

```
private string Encrypt(string clearText)
{
    string EncryptionKey = "ENC_KEY";
    byte[] clearBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(clearText); 
    using (Aes encryptor = Aes.Create())
    {
        Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0x10, 0x11 });
        encryptor.Key = pdb.GetBytes(32);
        encryptor.IV = pdb.GetBytes(16);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) {
        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, encryptor.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            cs.Write(clearBytes, 0, clearBytes.Length); cs.Close();
        }
        clearText = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray()); }
    }
    return clearText;
}
```

As i understand alghorithm generates AES key, and iv and encrypt and return as base 64 string.

I didn't find exact alternative for Rfc2898DeriveBytes and i used [PBKDF2 Gem](https://github.com/emerose/pbkdf2-ruby). And here is my ruby method:

```
def self.encrypt clear_text
  iterations = 1000
  encryption_key = 'EncryptionKey'
  clearBytes = clear_text.encode( 'UTF-16LE' ).bytes.to_a
  enc_bytes = [0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0x10, 0x11]
  salt = enc_bytes.pack('C*')
  derived_a = PBKDF2.new do |p|
    p.password = encryption_key
    p.salt = salt
    p.iterations = iterations
    p.key_length = 32
  end

  derived_b = PBKDF2.new do |p|
    p.password = encryption_key
    p.salt = salt
    p.iterations = iterations
    p.key_length = 16
  end

  key = derived_a.bin_string
  # iV = derived_b.bin_string
  iV_a = iV_a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16] # Static iV
  iV = iV_a.pack('C*')


  cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES256.new(:CBC)
  cipher.encrypt
  cipher.key = key
  cipher.iv = iV
  encrypted = cipher.update(clear_text) + cipher.final
  Base64.encode64(encrypted)
end
```

i have 2 problems in my code. i can't get same value on iv and if i use it as static value, return values doesn't match.

I don't have too many c# experience. What am i missing?

Comment: MSDN says getBytes function changes the key sizes on each calls.I mean if you call GetBytes(10), twice, it's the same as calling GetBytes(10+10) or directly GetBytes(20). There is some workaround for this issue, u can generate a longer key on the first call, then slicing it into both a derived key AND an IV.

Comment: If you do not have much C# experience, I would suggest that you not "translate" code, and just write it in Ruby from scratch. If you are more familiar with Ruby, this may be easier than trying to decipher an unknown language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your PBKDF2 generation algorithm has fixed input, so the resulting `Key` and `IV` should always be the same.

I just ran the C# code on my machine modified to output the values of the `Key` and `IV`. It gave me:

```
takKsX7IBXq3R0Q5GWgJo/XhhEHDNfRFxSVru12vtU4=
y/lm9eKzBJTMdU+uA6GlXA==
```

as the Base64 encoded values of the `Key` and `IV` respectively. You can just use these values in your Ruby code, that will remove the need to keep generating these using the PBKDF2 gem.

So this Ruby code

```
clear_text = 'HELLO WORLD'
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::AES256.new(:CBC)
cipher.encrypt
cipher.key = Base64.decode64('takKsX7IBXq3R0Q5GWgJo/XhhEHDNfRFxSVru12vtU4=')
cipher.iv = Base64.decode64('y/lm9eKzBJTMdU+uA6GlXA==')
clearBytes = clearText.encode('UTF-16LE')
encrypted = cipher.update(clearBytes)
encrypted << cipher.final
puts Base64.encode64(encrypted)
```

will output the same thing as `Encrypt("HELLO WORLD")`

Comment: Than you very much. when i set keys as base 64 strings problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you have different encryption keys

```
string EncryptionKey = "ENC_KEY";
Rfc2898DeriveBytes pdb = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(EncryptionKey, new byte[] { 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4, 0x5, 0x5, 0x5, 0x6, 0x7, 0x8, 0x9, 0x10, 0x11 });
```

Which is different from:

```
encryption_key = 'EncryptionKey'
...
derived_a = PBKDF2.new do |p|
    p.password = encryption_key
    p.salt = salt
    p.iterations = iterations
    p.key_length = 32
  end
```

If you truly are using the same "everything" you might need to make sure your passphrase is the same before KDF-ing it :)

Also, don't forget to [pack your IV in with your ciphertext](https://github.com/rdev5/crypto-wrapper/blob/master/lib/crypto-wrapper.js#L171) since you don't want that (or your salt) to be static, encrypt then MAC, all that good stuff :)